# Implementing ActionBarCompat causes r.java file to go missing

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I have an application in which I decided to implement ActionBarCompat since it's a google support library and many people recommend it over ActionBarSherlock. I first added it to Eclipse as a library project and connected it to my current project that I'm working on.

I then added a new menu item (refresh) like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
    android:title="@string/action_refresh"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

</menu>
```

And then called onCreateOptionsMenu like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.schedule, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

And when I try to compile the app it give out an error (before it even compiles):

> Error generating final archive: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\AndroidDevelopment\Workspace\STPSUrnik\bin\resources.ap_ does not exist

And if I clean the project, my r.java file goes missing.

This error disappears if I delete the refresh menu item's attribute "icon" and "title" which uses ActionBarCompat resources, so I'm guessing the problem is connecting to ActionBarCompat resources or something.

Comment: Why are you using the `android` xml namespace for one `showAsAction` attribute and the `app` namespace for the other one?

Comment: @NasaGeek as far as I know, I'm supposed to use app namespace for the first one so that the app knows it's ActionBarCompat while the other one is basic setting (non-library) so it has a normal namespace

Comment: I'm tempted to say that is not the case (as indicated [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#XmlAttributes)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. There really was a problem with resources. I had to manually download a "refresh" icon for action bar and put it in my application project.

It now works as it should!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with Eclipse. Sometimes the R.java file is still not restored after cleaning the project.

You can try to delete the gen and bin from the project directory and again try to import the project and clean it.

Maybe that will help.

Try to use Android Studio.. Till now I didn't get any issues with the R.java.

Comment: This isn't the problem. R.java is easily restored after I delete that one line.